# To Find the extreme values of the function by Lagrange method of undetermined multipliers

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, stationary-point

Find extreme values of the function $f(x,y) = xy$ on the surface $g(x,y) = \frac {x^2}{8} + \frac {y^2}{2} - 1 = 0$.

My approach :

First I created an auxilliary function $F(x,y,λ) = xy + λ(\frac {x^2}{8} + \frac {y^2}{2} - 1)$
Then I equated $\partial{F/\partial{x}} = 0$,  $\partial{F/\partial{y}} = 0$ and $\partial{F/\partial{λ}} = 0$.

I got the stationary points as: $(2,1), (-2,1), (-2,-1), (2,-1)$, where $λ = \frac{-x}{y}$.

How to proceed from here ? Should I directly put the stationary points in $f(x,y)$ and get its value ? In that case how will I know which points are extreme as some points may be saddle points also.

I needed a method of solving this question by finding double partial derivative.

Comment: You can try the bordered Hessian, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833468/lagrange-multipliers-method-of-solving-question/1833502#1833502)

Comment: What do you mean by geometrical method?

Comment: Someone posted a graphical method, this was in reference to that. I will update it.

Comment: Does the link help? Can you see that there the second partial derivatives are made?

Comment: Yes I got the answer from Hessian method. But what if det H(x0,y0)=0 in that method?

Comment: Then you cannot make a max/min-decision with the bordered Hessian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving $F(x,y,λ) = xy + λ(\frac {x^2}{8} + \frac {y^2}{2} - 1)\Rightarrow \cases{\partial{F/\partial{x}} = 0\\ \partial{F/\partial{y}} = 0\\ \partial{F/\partial{λ}} = 0}$ we obtain
four solutions

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
x y & x & y & \lambda\\
 2 & -2 & -1 & -2 \\
 -2 & -2 & 1 & 2 \\
 -2 & 2 & -1 & 2 \\
 2 & 2 & 1 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

as can be depicted in the attached plot. See the four tangent points between the level curves from $x y$ and the elliptical constraint $\frac {x^2}{8} + \frac {y^2}{2} - 1=0$. We have two minima and two maxima.

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. Can we have a geometrical solution to it by finding double partial derivative instead of graphical method? I will update this in my question also.

Comment: As the constraint is active, eliminating $y$ in $x y = f, \frac {x^2}{8} + \frac {y^2}{2} - 1=0$ we get at $f^2=\frac 14 x^2(8-x^2)$ and then we can verify at $x = \pm 2$ the behavior from $f$. We can use also the bordered hessian method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix

Comment: Yes I got the answer from bordered hessian method. Thanks a lot.